How to change the LOCALAPPDATA environment variable in PowerShell?
I'm trying to change the location of the %LOCALAPPDATA% environment variable in PowerShell, but the change is not taking effect.
Details of the Problem
I want to set the LOCALAPPDATA variable to a new directory (G:\AppData\Local), but after following several methods, it still shows the default location (C:\Users\username\AppData\Local) in PowerShell and other applications.
What I Tried

Set the environment variable using [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable():
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("LOCALAPPDATA", "G:\AppData\Local", "User")


The variable should reflect the new path in the current PowerShell session.


Verified the change using echo $env:LOCALAPPDATA:

The command shows the new location, but it's not reflected in other applications.


Restarted Powershell:

Closed and reopened PowerShell, but the change is still not visible.






While the paths of known (special) folders are reflected in environment variables, they cannot be changed that way.

In fact, such environment variables are volatile ones that are set by the system and seemingly override any attempts to set them as regular, persisted variables.


Use SHSetKnownFolderPath to change the location of known folders. It must be invoked via P/Invoke with the KNOWNFOLDERID (GUID) of the target folder, which from PowerShell requires an Add-Type call; changing the location of a non-user-specific folder requires elevation.

A simpler, registry-based approach (for user-specific folders only, via HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders) is discouraged and not officially supported, but still seems to work in practice as of Windows 11.




Changing the path of known folder %LOCALAPPDATA% for the current user:
(
  Add-Type -NameSpace NS$PID -Name KnownFolderPath -PassThru -MemberDefinition @'
[DllImport("shell32.dll")]
public extern static int SHSetKnownFolderPath(ref Guid folderId, uint flags, IntPtr token, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string path);
'@
)::SHSetKnownFolderPath(
  [ref] [guid] '{F1B32785-6FBA-4FCF-9D55-7B8E7F157091}', # folder ID
  0, # flags
  [IntPtr]::Zero, # target the current user
  'G:\AppData\Local' # new path
)

Note:

A return value of 0 indicates success.

The change takes effect:

immediately, when querying the known folders via APIs.
on the next logon / reboot with respect to the environment variable, $env:LOCALAPPDATA.

Alternatively, you can forcefully kill and thereby restart all Windows shell processes, and then start a new PowerShell session; however, note that this forcefully closes all open File Explorer windows and redraws the taskbar and desktop:
Stop-Process -Name explorer -Force





